# How to get distinct pairs for a table?

Tags: mysql

**Tables**

```
CREATE TABLE Users (user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                   name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE Ratings (user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                      rating INTEGER NOT NULL,
                      movie_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
                      PRIMARY KEY(user_id, movie_name),
                      FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES Users(user_id));
CREATE TABLE Similarity (user1_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                      user2_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                      similarity FLOAT,
                      PRIMARY KEY (user1_id, user2_id),
                      FOREIGN KEY (user1_id) REFERENCES Users(user_id),
                      FOREIGN KEY (user2_id) REFERENCES Users(user_id));
```

**Query:**  Find all distinct user pairs with a Similarityi,j >= 0.7 whose watch list overlaps in at least 12 movies. The result should contain three columns: the user id of the first user and the user id of the second user, and the number of movies they have watched.

**My Query:** Returns null

```
SELECT DISTINCT U.user_id, U2.user_id
FROM Users U, Users U2, Ratings R, Similarity S
WHERE U.user_id != U2.user_id AND
R.user_id = U.user_id AND 
R.user_id = U2.user_id AND 
S.similarity >= 0.7;
```

I realized `U.user_id != U2.user_id AND R.user_id = U.user_id AND R.user_id = U2.user_id` makes the table return null. But how do I get distinct user_id pairings?

Comment: I assume you are implying that User1_ID and user_2 ID could be 2,1 or 1,2 and you only want one of those... use either `>` or `<` instead of `!=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the tables

e.g.

```
    FROM User U 
    JOIN Ratings R ON U.user_id = R.User_id
    JOIN Similarity S ON S.user2_id = U.user_id
```

I would join them first and then use your where clause